# Build artifact is ignoring empty folder in aws codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

My folder structure contains an empty *files* directory in `sites/default/files`. The *default* folder has 3 other files. the issue is that while making a build the empty files folder is ignored. This is my `buildspec.yml`

```
version: 0.2

#env:
  #variables:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #parameter-store:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"

phases:
  #install:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  #pre_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  build:
    commands:
      - composer install --no-dev
  post_build:
    commands:
      - ls web/sites/default/
      - chmod 0775 web/sites/default/files
artifacts:
  files:
    - web/sites/default/*
  name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  #base-directory: location
#cache:
  #paths:
```

using `web/sites/default/**/*` also is ignoring it. Presently i am making a random file in the files directory to inclide the files folder, but i want to avoid this hack and include the folder the right way.
I am also attaching the snapshot of the build log.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create an empty index.html or txt file so that it doesn't ignore my folder and set this as my file output in artifacts: - DEBUG_DIRECTORY/**/*